# NumberFormatException for Input String Java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am writing an appointment program in Java and am coming across an error which is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string : ""

for the following lines :

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at AppointmentNew.main(AppointmentNew.java:24)
```

The program is going through once, but once it gets to the end of its first run it gives me those errors.... For instance when I run the program as follows : I make the choice of "1" to make a new appointment, I then enter the date of my new appointment "mm/dd/yyyy", then I add an appointment description, and lastly I enter the type "Once, Daily, or Monthly".  After that finishes it should start back over with the very first line of "**Make Choice (1: New, 2: Print Range, 3: Print All, quit):"** But instead it gives me the errors I described above...

Here is my code I have.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AppointmentNew 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
  String choice = "";
  int choiceNum = 0;
  String date = "";
  String descrip = "";
  int type = 0;
  String typeChose = "";

  System.out.println("Welcome to Appointment App!\n");
  System.out.println("\t============================\n");

  do
  {
     System.out.print("\tMake Choice ( 1: New, 2: Print Range, 3: Print All, quit): ");
     choice = stdin.nextLine();

     choiceNum = Integer.parseInt(choice);

     if (choiceNum == 1)
     {
        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter New Appointment Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
        date = stdin.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter New Appointment Description: ");
        descrip = stdin.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter Type (1 = Once, 2 = Daily, 3 = Monthly): ");
        type = stdin.nextInt();
        if (type == 1)
        {
          Once once = new Once(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "One-Time";
        }
        else if (type == 2)
        {
          Daily daily = new Daily(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "Daily";
        }
        else
        {
          Monthly monthly = new Monthly(date, descrip);
           typeChose = "Monthly";
        }
          String stringToAdd = "";
          stringToAdd = ("\n\n\tNew " + typeChose + " Appointment Added for " + date + "\n");
          list.add(stringToAdd);

        System.out.println(stringToAdd);
        System.out.println("\t============================\n");

     }

     if (choiceNum == 2)
     {
     System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter START Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
     String lowDate = stdin.nextLine();
     System.out.print("\n\n\tEnter END Date in mm/dd/yyyy format: ");
     String highDate = stdin.nextLine();

     for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
         int dateSpot = list.get(i).indexOf(" ");
         if (list.get(i).compareTo(lowDate) <= 0 && list.get(i).compareTo(highDate) >= 0)
        {
           System.out.println(list.get(i));   
       }}
     }

     if (choiceNum == 3)
     {
       for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
       {
          System.out.println(list.get(i));     
       }
     }

  }while (choice != "quit");      
}
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: When you give a blank input,`Integer.parseInt`  cannot convert into a number. Hence the exception. Use this check if(choice.equalls("")){//do not parse}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add another call to nextLine() after this statement here:

```
type = stdin.nextInt();
// ED: stdin.nextLine();
```

This is because, when you grab an int from the Scanner, it doesn't consume the '\n' character that gets put on the input stream when the user hits enter.

Thus, when stdin.nextLine() is called again, the String "" is returned (everything not yet processed up to the next '\n' character), and Integer.parseInt doesn't know how to handle that, so you get an error.

Comment: the only other problem it is giving me is when I choose "quit" for the first choice in the program, it is giving me the same error as was described above.... Any suggestions?

Comment: Well now, Integer.parseInt("quit") isn't going to work very well, is it?  You'll have to add some code to fix that :p

Comment: Haha funny! I figured that much :/ Any suggestions on getting it to work ??

Answer (score 0):

Surround the code with an if statement to check if the value is not quit before trying to Parse it.